# How to change navigation bar and barbuttonitem color & font on Modal view of activity in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have set the status bar to light content by setting `view-controller based status bar` in Info.plist to `No` as i am using dark color for navigation bar. I was able to set navigation bar color and bar button item color and font using following code in `AppDelegate.swift` -

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false


    if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0, weight: UIFontWeightThin)], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(23.0, weight: UIFontWeightThin), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UINavigationBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0, weight: UIFontWeightThin)], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions

    }
```

i have few issues below :-

1. I am not able to set navigation bar color for share activity - Skype, inbox (Gmail mail app) on `UIActivityViewController`
2. Not able to set barButtonItem e.g. "Cancel" font & size using `UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UINavigationBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0, weight: UIFontWeightThin)], forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

I tried to write same code in completion block for `UIActivityViewController` but nothing works.

3. When i select a chat from Recent Chats on whatsapp share activity, the barbuttonitem color turns to default blue  - 
   [See Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6yC6.png)
   [image]
4. Above all, the solutions i used support iOS version 8.0, 8.2 or higher. I want to achieve all the same for versions starting from 7.0 or 7.1 . How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Navigation bar appearance (background and title)

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor titleColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontNAme" size:titleSize], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor barColor]];

// Navigation bar buttons appearance

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor textBarColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, shadowColor, NSShadowAttributeName, [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:titleSize], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
```

Comment: I was able to achieve by the code i mentioned. My issue is - i can not set the nav bar color and bar button color for **Skype** app and **Inbox** app modal view of share activity on UIActivityViewController

Comment: Also, for Whatsapp share activity bar button item color once user selects a recent chat. Refer the snapshot